# Starting jupyter notebook with conda environment from docker

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook, conda, environment

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM jupyter/datascience-notebook
RUN conda create -c rdkit -n my-rdkit-env rdkit
RUN echo "source activate my-rdkit-env" > ~/.bashrc
ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/env/bin:$PATH
```

that I build with the following command:

```
sudo docker build -t demo .
```

When I run this interactively with the following:

```
sudo docker run -it demo bash
```

I can see my environment is activated. However, when I open a jupyter notebook with the following:

```
sudo docker run -it -v {my_path}:/home/jovyan/notebooks --rm -p 8888:8888 demo
```

Then I get a jupyter dashboard where I can see the environment activated in the terminals that I start, but I cannot get any notebooks to start with the environment activated. Advice?

output from last command above that results in the notebook i described in previous paragraph:

```
Executing the command: jupyter notebook
[I 08:46:06.674 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /home/jovyan/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
[I 08:46:08.180 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 08:46:08.180 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is /opt/conda/share/jupyter/lab
[I 08:46:08.182 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/jovyan
[I 08:46:08.182 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 08:46:08.182 NotebookApp] http://(3a03022aa4dc or 127.0.0.1):8888/?token=081a6dc774dd7edbbb7c6940f7db4b5a285703b6e7265449
[I 08:46:08.182 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 08:46:08.182 NotebookApp] 

    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://(3a03022aa4dc or 127.0.0.1):8888/?token=081a6dc774dd7edbbb7c6940f7db4b5a285703b6e7265449
```

Comment: I see where you are creating a conda virtualenv, activating your virtualenv, but I'm not seeing where you are launching the jupyter process.  For example, to launch a jupyter-lab notebook, I would typically type something like this into my terminal: `jupyter-lab --port=<portnumber> --ip=<hostname> --notebook-dir=<directory>`

Comment: The docker run command launches the notebook. It outputs "Executing the command: jupyter notebook" and eventually gives the address the server is running at: "http://{hostname}:8888/?token={token}". I'll add the full output to the original question

Comment: Hi @EddiesFan were you able to fix this problem? Having a similar issue